# download leaderboard reports into a csv rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, leaderboard

I have a reports controller where I have leaderboard. I would like to download the leader board into a csv file
here is the leaderboard code

```
def leaderboard
      if params.has_key?(:start_date) && params.has_key?(:end_date) && params.has_key?(:account)
        if params[:unit] == 'all'
          @start_date = current_user.created_at
          @end_date = Time.now
        else
          @start_date = Time.at(params[:start_date].to_i/1000)
          @end_date = Time.at(params[:end_date].to_i/1000)
        end

        if params[:account] == 'all'
          user_accounts = current_user.accounts.collect{ |a| a.id }
          ActsAsTenant.without_tenant do
            @conversations = Conversation.where(account_id: user_accounts).updated_between(@start_date,@end_date)
            @users = current_user.accounts.collect{|account| account.users}.flatten.uniq.to_a
            unassigned = User.new(name: 'Un-assigned')
            @users << unassigned
          end
        else
          account = Account.find(params[:account])
          ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(account) do
            @conversations = account.conversations.updated_between(@start_date,@end_date)
            @users = account.users.to_a
            unassigned = User.new(name: 'Un-assigned')
            @users << unassigned
          end
        end
      else
        render json: {error: 'Invalid parameters'}, status: 422
      end
    end
```

here is the image of the data I want to be able to download as csv
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI6lo.png

here is the leaderboard.json.jbuider

```
json.users @users do |user|
   json.(user,:id, :name)
   json.closed_count @conversations.where(user: user).closed.count
   json.open_count   @conversations.where(user: user).open.count
   json.replies      @conversations.where(user: user).inject(0){|sum, conversation| sum + conversation.messages.where(updated_at: @start_date..@end_date).where(direction: 'OUT').count}
   json.resolution_time formatted_duration(array_mean(@conversations.closed.where(user: user).closed.collect{ |c| c.resolution_time }))
   json.first_response Conversation.first_response(@conversations.where(user: user))
end

json.total_closed   @conversations.closed.count
json.total_open     @conversations.open.count
json.total_replies  @conversations.inject(0){|sum, conversation| sum + conversation.messages.where(updated_at: @start_date..@end_date).where(direction: 'OUT').count}
json.start_date @start_date.to_i * 1000
json.end_date @end_date.to_i * 1000
```

How do I go about downloading it into a csv?

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet I'm not sure what you're trying to "export", but in general it should look like:

```rb
csv_lines = []

@some_data.each do |record|
  csv_lines << "#{record.field1};#{record.field2};#{record.field3}" #and so on
end

#export csv_lines
txt = csv_lines.join "\n"
```

Comment: I edited the question and added an image of the code output

Comment: can you provide view source?

Comment: As I understood `leaderboard` method is generating view you want to export? Right? I'd like to see `leaderboard.html.erb`

Comment: I don't have  html.erb I have leaderboard.json.jbuilder

Comment: the data is being rendered via react